# Can't emulate going through the link: Method not allowed error (#405)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, yii2, codeception, http-status-code-405

I'm writing acceptance/ functional test for the website and have the following problem.

On the website there is a menu:

```
<ul class="b">
<li ng-repeat="item2 in item.items" class="ng-scope">
  <a href="/persons/personaccount/index" class="ng-binding">Account</a>
</li><li ng-repeat="item2 in item.items" class="ng-scope">
  <a href="/persons/persontype/index" class="ng-binding">Person type</a>
</li><li ng-repeat="item2 in item.items" class="ng-scope">
  <a href="/persons/person/index" class="ng-binding">Person</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

In common mode, I can freely click on any item.
In one continuous Cept- file I can call the method:

```
$I->click('//*[@class="b"]/li[last()]/a');
```

Then loaded the page that I need.

The problem occurs when I use the class-like Cest format (I prefer it). If I make this call from the method where I pass authorization, for example:

```
public function tryToDoSomething(FunctionalTester $I)
{
    $I->amOnPage('/site/login');

    $I->fillField('#loginform-username','admin');
    $I->fillField('#loginform-password','admin');

    $I->seeElement('button', ['name' => 'login-button']);

    $I->click('#login-form button[type=submit]');

    $I->wait(5);

    $I->cantSee('....', '.error-block');

    ... 
    $I->click('//*[@class="b"]/li[last()]/a'); // <<-----
}
```

Then the page loads. However, if I moved this call to another method, 
where it is more logically appropriate, for example:

```
public function tryToDoSomething(FunctionalTester $I)
{
    $I->amOnPage('/site/login');
    ...
    $I->cantSee('....', '.error-block');

    ...     
}

public function TryToDoAnythingElse(FunctionalTester $I)
{
    ...
    $I->click('//*[@class="b"]/li[last()]/a'); // <<-----
    ...
}
```

Then, I get the following error:

> **Method Not Allowed (#405).** This url can only handle
>   the following request methods: . The above error occurred while the
>   Web server was processing your request.
>
> Please contact us if you think this is a server error. Thank you.

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the solution seems to me the following..
All methods except one I marked as `protected` so they won’t be executed as tests.

Then I call them from the "main" test method:

```
protected function tryToDoSomething(FunctionalTester $I)
{
    $I->amOnPage('/site/login');
    ...
    $I->cantSee('....', '.error-block');

    ...     
}

public function tryToDoAnythingElse(FunctionalTester $I)
{
    tryToDoSomething($I);
    $I->click('//*[@class="b"]/li[last()]/a');
    ...
}
```

If I use this approach, the error will not occur.

Then the whole test can be represented as a sequence of calls to protected methods:

```
public function tryToGoThroughTheFlow(FunctionalTester $I) 
{
    $this->tryToA($I);
    $this->tryToB($I);
    $this->tryToC($I);
    $this->tryToD($I);
    ...
}
```

, where:

```
protected function tryToA(FunctionalTester $I) 
{
   ...
}

protected function tryToB(FunctionalTester $I) 
{
   ...
}
```

And so on. Although the cause of the error remains unclear.. I'm sending the request of the not allowed type?

Comment: Have you found out the root of the problem? 
Concerning the calls to the protected methods: you can as well execute them just adding the annotations to the "main" test method: @before tryToA .

Comment: I am facing the same problem, though I use acceptance tests. I've tried WebDriver and PhpBrowser and both give the error "Method Not Allowed (#405)" once I click on "delete" link with enforced "post" method.

Comment: I have some doubts for two reasons: 1. if I myself perform all steps of the test, then everthing works well, 2. if I change the link to use its standard method "GET" instread of "POST", the test passes. 

I think that the problem is somehow related to the Codeception and its browser.